# Android OpenGL ES read texture pixels

Tags: java, android, opengl-es

The preview from my camera is rendered to a texture. I have the textureId and am trying to render the texture on a `FBO` so I can `glReadPixels`.

When I do actually read the pixels, all of them appear to be black though.

This is the code I am using at the moment:

```
//called when the camera first connects to the texture
public void initBackBuffer()
    {
  // For use in getFramePixels()
        intBuffer = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(width *
            height * 4)
            .order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder())
            .asIntBuffer();
        IntBuffer framebuffer = IntBuffer.allocate(1);
        glGenFramebuffers(1, framebuffer);
        glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, framebuffer.get(0));
        int status = glGetError();
        if(status != GL_NO_ERROR)
        {
            Log.e("RENDERER", status + "");
        }

        IntBuffer depthBufferName = IntBuffer.allocate(1);

        glGenRenderbuffers(1, depthBufferName);
        glBindRenderbuffer(GL_RENDERBUFFER, depthBufferName.get(0));
        glRenderbufferStorage(GL_RENDERBUFFER, GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT16, width, height);
        glFramebufferRenderbuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_DEPTH_ATTACHMENT, GL_RENDERBUFFER,
                depthBufferName.get(0));
       glFramebufferTexture2D(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0, GL_TEXTURE_2D,
                mTangoCameraTexture.getTextureId(), 0);
        mOffscreenBuffer = framebuffer.get(0);
        status = glCheckFramebufferStatus(GL_FRAMEBUFFER);

        if(status != GL_FRAMEBUFFER_COMPLETE) {
            if(status == GL_FRAMEBUFFER_INCOMPLETE_ATTACHMENT)
                Log.e("RENDERER","GL_FRAMEBUFFER_INCOMPLETE_ATTACHMENT");
            if(status == GL_FRAMEBUFFER_INCOMPLETE_MISSING_ATTACHMENT)
                Log.e("RENDERER", "GL_FRAMEBUFFER_INCOMPLETE_MISSING_ATTACHMENT_EXT");
            Log.e("RENDERER", "FRAMEBUFFER ERROR:"+status);

        }
        glBindFramebuffer( GL_FRAMEBUFFER, 0 );

    }
// called onFrameAvailable
public void getFramePixels() {
    glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, mOffscreenBuffer);
    int status = glCheckFramebufferStatus(GL_FRAMEBUFFER);
    if(status != GL_FRAMEBUFFER_COMPLETE)
    {
        Log.e(TAG, "FRAMEBUFFER STATUS:"+status);
    }
    glReadPixels(0, 0, width, height, GL_RGBA,
            GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE,
            intBuffer.clear());
    StringBuilder str = new StringBuilder();
    for(int i = 0; i < intBuffer.capacity(); i++)
    {
        str.append(intBuffer.get(););
    }
    Log.d(TAG, "IMAGE:" + str.toString());
    glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, 0);

}
```

If I display the texture on the screen, I am able to see it - so the texture not being actually bound to the camera is excluded.

**Edit:** there's a `GL_INVALID_OPERATION` happening at `glFramebufferTexture2D(GL_FRAMEBUFFER,GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0,GL_TEXTURE_2D, getTextureId(), 0);` for some reason.

From the docs:

> GL_INVALID_OPERATION is generated if zero is bound to target.
>   GL_INVALID_OPERATION is generated if textarget and texture are not compatible.

My `textureId` is `1`.

Answer (score 0):

Read the docs more carefully. Your texture ID may be 1, but what you have currently bound to the target is likely actually 0. If you don't call `glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, mTangoCameraTexture.getTextureId());` then `GL_TEXTURE_2D` (the target) is whatever you set it to last, which I'm inclined to say is probably 0.

If you find you have performance issues surrounding `glReadPixels()` you should consider using it alongside a Pixel Buffer Object.